# Decoding Key Values from /dev/input/eventx in C

Tags: c, devices, input-devices, events, ascii

I have created a keylogger in C that displays the raw key values from an input device. I am wondering how I would go about decoding hese values into ascii characters? Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void INThandler(){
        exit(0);
}

int main()
{
        char devname[] = "/dev/input/event3";
        int device = open(devname, O_RDONLY);
        struct input_event ev;

        signal(SIGINT, INThandler);

        while(1)
        {
                read(device,&ev, sizeof(ev));
                if(ev.type == 1 && ev.value == 1){
                        printf("Key: %i State: %i\n",ev.code,ev.value);
                }
        }
}
```

Example Output:

```
Key: 32 State: 1
Key: 42 State: 1
Key: 29 State: 1
```

I  know that these values are ordinal numbers for the placement of the keys on the keyboard device, and aren't ascii codes, so is there some system file containing the instructions for conversion? I do not want to do the conversion manually because it will be different for all keyboard devices.

Thanks, any help is appreciated

Comment: Other than the fact `while(1)` looks like an infinite loop of my life, what keys did you press for `Key` 32, 42, 29. Do you think they are in hexadecimal and require conversion to decimal for ASCII? ie Hex 32 = Decimal 50 = "2", Hex 42 = Dec 66 = "B" and Hex 29 = Dec 41 = ")". If you pressed `2`, `B`, `)` they are hexadecimal.

Comment: I know that these numbers are not hex, but they are ordinal values for the location of the keys on the keyboard device. If I press 'a', then 'b' I will not get consecutive numbers, however if I input 'qwertyui' (they are all on the same line), I will get consecutive values. I was wondering if there was a system file containing this conversion, since it will be different for all keyboard devices.

Comment: The values are not hex, Logan properly mentioned that. `xev` shows exactly the same keycodes. Problem is that they are not necessarily "letters" , but can be assigned letters depending on the keyboard layout used by the X server GUI.  I'd suggest you look into `xev` source code and see how they did it. I bet they use some form of library that does the translation

Comment: If you google `Low-Level Internal Key Numbers`  I believe what you are looking for shows up. For some reason when I paste the link into this AskUbuntu comment it takes you to a sign on screen instead.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Unfortunately, those codes do not match up at all with the output I'm getting (i.e it says Q is 39 when my program outputs 16).

Comment: @Logan, sorry but I tried :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix After Further searching I did find some leads, I will continue my search in the morning

Comment: It's amazing how many problems I worked out whilst dreaming. Good-night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to obtain the keymaps and use it to translate those codes you read from the file descriptor to the ASCII characters you want to log.

On Ubuntu, you can obtain the keymap with the command `dumpkeys` (run as root) or the command `xmodmap -pke`. For some reason, I don't quite understand yet, the output of `xmodmap` seems to have an offset. You can correct this offset easily, but I'm not aware of what is the reason behind it. Maybe it has to do with the `xmodmap` being originally written for Sun Microsystems and X11 using different keycodes (as it seems to be suggested [here](http://www.verycomputer.com/39_7016b6b3e7c33479_1.htm)), but I'm just guessing out loud..

Comment: Thank you! Would you happen to know if the offset is constant? Or does it change periodically?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe it is constant. The output of `dumpkeys` doesn't have this offset, so you could use it instead.